# Using wildcards in getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, facebook, wildcard, getelementsbyclassname

I'm making a js function for a Chrome extension that replaces content in the Facebook newsfeed. Each post has the class `uiUnifiedStory uiStreamStory genericStreamStory aid_1719315288 uiListItem uiListLight uiListVerticalItemBorder` where `aid` always changes.

If I want to get all the classes, I can't just use `aid_*`.

How can I get all of the `li` elements that match the class `uiUnifiedStory uiStreamStory genericStreamStory aid_* uiListItem uiListLight uiListVerticalItemBorder` where aid can be anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many libraries that allow selection by wildcard, however you can do it manually by:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName( /* class names other than aid_* ones */
var re = new RegExp('(^|\\s)aid_(\\s|$)'); 
var result = [];

for (var i=0, iLen=elements.length; i<iLen; i++) {
  if (re.test(elements[i].className)) {
    result.push(elements[i]);
  }
}
```

Note that [getElementsByClassName](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/dom.html#getelementsbyclassname) returns a live [NodeList](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-536297177), but *result* will be a native Array (as will whatever is returned by the various library implementations of getElementsByClassName).

You can also use [querySelectorAll](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/#queryselectorall), which I think is more widely supported than getElementsByClassName.

#### Edit

So you tried:

```
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('uiUnifiedStory uiStreamStory' +
                 ' genericStreamStory aid_173333252718885 aid_183319479511' +
                 ' uiListItem uiListLight uiListVerticalItemBorder');

  var re = new RegExp('(^|\\s)aid_(\\s|$)');
  var result = [];

  for (var i=0, iLen=elements.length; i<iLen; i++) {

    if (re.test(elements[i].className)) {
      result.push(elements[i]);
      elements.innerHTML = "<h6>benrox!</h6>";
```

Ooops, elements is  a NodeList, assigning to its innerHTML property either does nothing useful or throws an error. Likely you meant to set the property of the current member of the NodeList:

```
      elements[i].innerHTML = "<h6>benrox!</h6>";
      --------^^^
```

Note that you can edit your question if you have something to add.

Comment: thanks mate! When you say "class names other than aid_* ones" What do you mean? This? uiUnifiedStory uiStreamStory genericStreamStory uiListItem uiListLight uiListVerticalItemBorder

Comment: Sorry for asking, but Im quite the noob.

Comment: Why isnt this working? `var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('uiUnifiedStory uiStreamStory genericStreamStory aid_173333252718885 aid_183319479511 uiListItem uiListLight uiListVerticalItemBorder');
var re = new RegExp('(^|\\s)aid_(\\s|$)'); 
var result = [];

for (var i=0, iLen=elements.length; i<iLen; i++) {
  if (re.test(elements[i].className)) {
    result.push(elements[i]);
    elements.innerHTML = "<h6>benrox!</h6>";
  }
}`

Comment: Because you are still putting specific aid_123456789 classnames into the first selector? The comment in Rob’s script explicitely say, _“class names __other__ than aid* ones”_ …

Comment: @CBroe I know that, but do I include the rest of the class name other than aid_whatever?